# Windows credential provider pinlogonprovider

Tags: windows, credential-providers

I am trying to make a Windows custom credential provider using this reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-classic-samples/credential-provider/

[https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53556#:~:text=Credential%20providers%20are%20used%20in,for%20Windows%20Vista%20and%20higher](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53556#:%7E:text=Credential%20providers%20are%20used%20in,for%20Windows%20Vista%20and%20higher)

The idea is:

1. I kept the username and password inside the pc
2. I use my own MFA (just simple push notification to my android phone)
3. If I confirm the notification, I will use the stored username & password to login

It works well whenever I match the password and Username, and login using my "Credential Provider"

Then I realize, after I login to my Microsoft username, The next login will be prompted PIN instead of password like this:

[image]

I know I can keep my Microsoft account's Password to my offline database and my idea is still working.

However, since my password is too long, I want to keep the pin instead of the password

Does Windows credential provider support PIN authentication?

I tried to google it, and it just showing the smartcard's pin instead of the Windows Logon Pin

------------------- UPDATE ------------

Looks like I did not write the question clearly

I want to extend my current Credential Provider that able to automatically sign in using password and Windows Hello PIN.

So the Database will consist of username and PIN (that match with Windows Hello PIN) or Password (that match with Local account password)

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look how you set-up new logon using `Picture` or `PIN` credential providers from `Microsoft Hello` - initially you enter your password.
So these providers store this collected data in some internals and later provide them as collected by themself.
Nobody restrict you from doing the same way.

------------------- UPDATE ------------

Have a look at [SampleWrapExistingCredentialProvider](https://github.com/alexyack/CredentialProviders/tree/master/SampleWrapExistingCredentialProvider)

Comment: Yes, that's correct (In case of pin I agree). So the credential that all of provider in windows agrees/accept is password?
I want to verify my account with existing windows `PIN` (not make a new pin provider), instead of existing windows password. Is it possible?

Comment: In my use case I have been implemented additional credential provider to eliminate appearance of PIN-input dialog (Windows Security) from one of smart-card vendors. Try to trace all calls to your provider. Maybe you can find some points where you can change the behaviour.

Comment: How to trace all calls to provider? In my case, using `plogger.h` library, I made a log files. Is there any other way to trace the provider calls?

Comment: I have been writing my own logging subsystem and put a call to log each method that have been implemented and then called.

Comment: Ah i see, same method then. Thank you

Comment: Have a look at [SampleWrapExistingCredentialProvider](https://github.com/alexyack/CredentialProviders/tree/master)